# Access 2013 run time error 3061, Too few parameters. Expected 1 and other oddities

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've begun developing a reasonably simple access project. The DB and queries were built via the app and I have some code which would run through a table and populate another table based on content. This worked fine until I added an additional field (AsOfDate) to one of the tables and I now get the 3061 error when querying the table. If I remove the new field from the SQL it works fine.
So I've looked at the table object when debugging - can't see the new field and also noticed that another Query I setup doesn't get enumerated either.

Is there something I'm missing here in regard to what I'm doing in the front end app versus what I need to do in the VBA ?

The code is simple (so far) but I'll include it hear for reference.

```
Public Sub PopulateBillingRecords()

'Quick and dirty attempt to replicate desk billing

Dim wrkSpace As Workspace
Dim dbThisDB As DAO.Database
Dim tblUsers As TableDef
Dim tblPermissions As TableDef
Dim tblTrades As TableDef
Dim tblBilling As TableDef
Dim rsUsers As Recordset
Dim rsPermissions As Recordset
Dim rsTrades As Recordset
Dim rsBilling As DAO.Recordset
Dim qryBilling As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strBillingSQL As String
Dim qryUsers As QueryDef
Dim strUsersSQL As String
Dim rowUser As Variant
Dim datAsOfDate As Date
Dim qryTemp As QueryDef
Dim fldThisField As Field
Dim flsAllFields As Fields
Dim strTempField As String

Set wrkSpace = CreateWorkspace("GVUsers", "admin", "", dbUseJet)


Set dbThisDB = wrkSpace.OpenDatabase("GV User Analysis.accdb")

Set tblUsers = dbThisDB.TableDefs("Users")
Set tblPermissions = dbThisDB.TableDefs("MarketPermissions")
Set tblTrades = dbThisDB.TableDefs("Trades")
Set tblBilling = dbThisDB.TableDefs("Billing")

tblBilling.Fields.Refresh
dbThisDB.TableDefs.Refresh

datAsOfDate = Date


'Assuming existing tables populate by import *code import routine later*

'Clear out any existing billing records 'in future allow data to persist and prompt to either clear down data for current billing period if it exists or append

Set rsBilling = Nothing

strBillingSQL = "SELECT Billing.ID,  Billing.CompanyCode, Billing.CompanyName, Billing.TraderName, Billing.TraderID, Billing.ConnectionType," _
& "Billing.IsDisabled, Billing.SetupDate, Billing.TPLogCount, Billing.HasConcession, Billing.IsBillable, Billing.BillingPeriod, Billing.DeskByOrdersTrades," _
& "Billing.DeskByPermissions, Billing.OverallDeskAllocation, Billing.HasGasPermissions, Billing.HasPowerPermissions, Billing.HasCoalPermissions, Billing.TradesCount," _
& "Billing.OrdersCount, Billing.AllocationGas, Billing.AllocationPower, Billing.AllocationCoal, Billing.AllocationMethod,Billing.AsOfDate" _
& " FROM Billing;"


Set rsBilling = dbThisDB.OpenRecordset(strBillingSQL, dbOpenDynaset) '<----   3061 error is returned here
```

I'm going nuts trying to work out what's going on and think that starting over isn't the solution!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't worked much with TableDef, but it seems to me (not sure, but worth trying) that you probably need to remake your TableDef object in access after you have modified the table.

Comment: Double check the name of the field in your table. This error usually indicates you're trying to use a parameter in VBA, which access doesn't like.  Since you have no Where statement it most likely can't find "Billing.AsOfDate" and thinks that it is a parameter. Can you post the Billing table in Design view? (making sure to include the AsOfDate

Comment: Also.. If you're only using one table in your query, there's no need to specify "Billing" before every field.

Comment: That seems very strange.  I would try.   A.   Renaming the AsOfdate Column to see anything chnages, perhaps changing the data type to.    B. Changing the select to be "SELECT *" and see if you can see all the fields.  Also capture the SQL generated and try running it in the SQL designer in the source database.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: `datAsOfDate = Date` ? You are setting a classtype to a variable declared as this type. Does not make sense to me. If you want to create this datAsOfDate - field in the table you need another piece of code.

Comment: Perhaps worth a try: Open your backend database (GV User Analysis.accdb) and do a **Compact & Repair**. -- Also (since it's apparently not helping) try commenting out all the `TableDefs` operations.

Comment: Thanks all. The SQL in the code was copied from a working query built in the FE and names have not been changed etc. (that's why fields are preceded by the table name (Gene). When run the FE the query doesn't prompt for a parameter which I would expect if that was the problem.

Comment: I've run a compact & repair on the db but it didn't help. AsOfDate is specified at runtime in order to keep track of records over time.

Comment: I'll give removing tabledefs a go as well.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it's with sadness and regret (and crossed fingers) that I'll have to start again.

Answer (score 1):

It can be cut down to this:

```
Dim wrkSpace As Workspace
Dim dbThisDB As DAO.Database
Dim rsBilling As DAO.Recordset
Dim strBillingSQL As String

Set wrkSpace = CreateWorkspace("GVUsers", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
Set dbThisDB = wrkSpace.OpenDatabase("GV User Analysis.accdb")

strBillingSQL = "SELECT Billing.ID,  Billing.CompanyCode, Billing.CompanyName, Billing.TraderName, Billing.TraderID, Billing.ConnectionType," _
& "Billing.IsDisabled, Billing.SetupDate, Billing.TPLogCount, Billing.HasConcession, Billing.IsBillable, Billing.BillingPeriod, Billing.DeskByOrdersTrades," _
& "Billing.DeskByPermissions, Billing.OverallDeskAllocation, Billing.HasGasPermissions, Billing.HasPowerPermissions, Billing.HasCoalPermissions, Billing.TradesCount," _
& "Billing.OrdersCount, Billing.AllocationGas, Billing.AllocationPower, Billing.AllocationCoal, Billing.AllocationMethod,Billing.AsOfDate" _
& " FROM Billing;"

Set rsBilling = dbThisDB.OpenRecordset(strBillingSQL, dbOpenDynaset) '<----   3061 error is returned here
```

That error indicates, that a field in strBillingSQL is misspelled or does not exist in the table.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. The SQL in the code was copied from a working query built in the FE and names have not been changed etc. (that's why fields are preceded by the table name

Comment: Add `Debug.Print strBillingSQL` (on the line before `Set rsBilling`) to the code Gustav gave you and run it.  Go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there) and copy the statement text.  Then open `GV User Analysis.accdb` in Access, create a new query in the query designer, switch it to SQL View, and paste in the text.  When you run that query, what is the name of the parameter for which Access asks you to supply a value?  (Whatever that name is, Access does not find a matching field name in that version of the `Billing` table.)

Comment: I always thought you had to use "& -" at the end of lines, and not "- &"  (replace the dash with underscore, for some reason the underscores weren't showing up)?